# How to save an Excel sheet and Word document into single pdf with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word, export-to-pdf

I know how to export an Excel sheet to pdf with VBA, and I have seen how to export a Word document to pdf with VBA. However, I can't figure out how to export both together to a single pdf. Is there a way to do this using VBA? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this without VBA... unless you're using Adobe's software...?

Comment: @pgSystemTester impossible to do with or without VBA?

Comment: You probably will have to generate two PDFs and merge them in Acrobat

Comment: I was suggesting that if it can't be done WITHOUT vba (which I believe is true statement?), I don't think it can be done with VBA.

Comment: You could, of course, insert the worksheet into the Word document before creating the PDF from Word alone...

Comment: @macropod I may end up doing that if there isn't a more straightforward method. I already have my Excel sheet formatted to print/export correctly in landscape orientation. The document it is supposed to attach to is in portrait orientation. Using VBA to insert the sheet into Word will probably require some reformatting before export.

Comment: In Word, you can already insert landscape pages into a portrait-format document via the simple expedient of using a Section break before the landscape pages (and after them if you're reverting to portrait format). Just be aware that, if you're inserting an actual workbook, the inserted object cannot span a page break - in which case you'd need to insert a different portion (or at least link to a different portion) for each new page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine both documents into a single one to get the job done. In VBA you can use the `Copy` and `Paste` methods available in both applications to create a single document and then use the [Document.ExportAsFixedFormat2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat2) method which saves a document in PDF or XPS format.